# How to add a listener on EditorStack?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I would like to detect the rearranging of editor tabs, so that when a tab is moved to a different position (in the same Part) I can recognize the tab order is changed. I suppose there should be a way to do it by a listener on the Editor Stack, but how to do it?
Thanks for any input.

Comment: Listening for parts being opened, closed, activated and deactivated is straightforward, but I am not aware of anything for movement in the tab. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @greg-449 Yes it is simple for activation/deactivation, but I need to detect the order of the tabs. The application has 2 perspectives and 2 kinds of editors (each perspective has its own editors). When switching perspective, editors of a specific type need to be hidden (and not to be shown on the other perspective): the default behavior is not satisfactory, because all editors are left visible. Fr this reason we are going to `page.getEditorReferences()` and hide the editors of a specific type. The problem is that `page.getEditorReferences()` lists the editors in creation, and not tab order...